# Корректно ли использование "как и ранее, и как далее"?

Tags: запятые, союзы

Корректно ли использование "как и ранее, и как далее"? И если да, то каким образом проставляются запятые в тексте?

> Для упрощения анализа работы здесь, как и ранее, и как далее, диод принят идеальным, то есть его коммутация происходит мгновенно, и прямое падение напряжения, и обратный ток равны нулю.

Comment: может быть "как и ранее, так и далее"?

Comment: Меня именно это и смутило. Я знаю, что есть "как...так и", но впервые встречаю двойное использование "как". Смысловое значение предложения понятно, однако является ли допустимым использования подобного в печатаемой литературе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"И как далее" лишнее. Уродство какое-то.

Писать нужно так, чтобы читающему было приятно, чтобы не было неоднозначности понимания. Лучше предложение построить по-другому. Или несколько предложений написать, добившись ясности!

Или же вы просто вырвали предложение из текста.

Comment: Насчёт отсутствия красоты в использовании подобного я согласен. Однако техническая литература полна и куда более худшими примерами. Касательно же второго: "и как далее" никак не может быть полностью лишним, т.к в противном случае теряется смысл, поэтому использование "и как далее" или же какого - либо эквивалента ему - обязательно, по моему мнению.

Comment: Если "и как далее" было сразу после "как и ранее" (и оба они до момента "здесь"), то между ними трудно поставить границу. "И как далее" сливается с "как и ранее", теряет свою самобытность и становится "как и ранее". Если же тут три отрезка времени , где "здесь" - в середине ("как и ранее", "здесь" и "и как далее"), то написано у Вас правильно.